# How to find a rotation matrix from 3 deformed points in python efficiently

Tags: python, numpy, math, linear-algebra

I am trying to find a rotation matrix between coordinate systems by using 3 unit vectors I have defined in both coordinate systems.
[image: coordinate rotation visualisation]

I am currently using a [method I found on Mathmatics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2004800/math-for-simple-3d-coordinate-rotation-python) which is defined as follow:
[image: rotation matrix equation]

A minimum working example of implementing this in python looks like:

```
p1 = [math.sqrt(2)/2,math.sqrt(2)/2,0]
p2 = [-math.sqrt(2)/2,math.sqrt(2)/2,0]
p3 = [0,0,1]
TT = np.vstack([p1, p2, p3]).T
TM = np.eye(3)
for i in range (0,2):
    for j in range(0,2):
        TM[i][j] = math.cos(angle_between_vectors(np.eye(3)[:,j],TT[i,:]))


def vector_norm(data, axis=None, out=None):
    data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float64, copy=True)
    if out is None:
        if data.ndim == 1:
            return math.sqrt(np.dot(data, data))
        data *= data
        out = np.atleast_1d(np.sum(data, axis=axis))
        np.sqrt(out, out)
        return out
    else:
        data *= data
        np.sum(data, axis=axis, out=out)
        np.sqrt(out, out)

def angle_between_vectors(v0, v1, directed=True, axis=0):
    v0 = np.array(v0, dtype=np.float64, copy=False)
    v1 = np.array(v1, dtype=np.float64, copy=False)
    dot = np.sum(v0 * v1, axis=axis)
    dot /= np.linalg.norm(v0, axis=axis) * vector_norm(v1, axis=axis)
    dot = np.clip(dot, -1.0, 1.0)
    return np.arccos(dot if directed else np.fabs(dot))
```

Does anyone know a way of calculating a rotation matrix with less code or more efficiency?

Comment: Sorry @ Warren Weckesser, you're right. I was trying to make a simple example but missed that. Will update now.

Comment: Are the 3 unit vectors for either frame guaranteed to be mutually orthogonal? If not you can use [Gram-Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to orthogonalize them. They will then form the rows of the rotation matrices for their respective frames.

Comment: In addition to @meowgoesthedog 's comment, once you have the rotation matrices (built from the orthonormal vectors) for the first and second coordinate systems, `R1` and `R2` respectively, the rotation matrix that takes you from the first to the second one would be `inv(R1) x R2`.

Comment: @jdehesa 1) also conveniently `inv(R1) == transpose(R1)`; 2) given that OP is using the column vector convention the correct rotation would be `R2 x inv(R1)`.